# How to exclude C++ raw string literals from syntax highlighting in Vim?

Tags: c++, vim, c++11, vim-syntax-highlighting, rawstring

Quite honestly, [raw string literals](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal) are a great addition to the C++ language. But (as expected) editors have a hard time to properly display those literals.

I am using Vim 7.4 and out-of-the-box raw string literals completely break the syntax highlighting. For example in

```
char const txt[] = R"(printf(")";
```

the 2nd '(' is highlighted red in vim.

Something like

```
char const txt2[] = R"(  "{{"  )";
```

breaks the highlighting of curly braces and the syntax based auto-ident - and so on.

For a start I would be happy to have Vim ignore everything between `R"(` and `)"` when doing syntax highlighting.

But note that raw string literals are flexible - arbitrary matching strings are allowed between the first/last double-quote/brace pair, e.g.

```
R"abcd()")")abcd"
```

is also a valid raw string literal which encodes

```
)")"
```

See also the cppreference link for a general definition of the syntax.

Thus my question how to configure Vim such that C++ raw string literals are properly recognized.

Vim already seems to include some facilities to properly synatx highlight language fragments embedded in a host language (e.g. for compiler-compiler source files). Perhaps they can be used for the raw string literal case as well?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just add [cpp-vim](https://github.com/vim-jp/cpp-vim) as a plugin. I have added strict support for newer string literals in [pull-request #14](https://github.com/vim-jp/cpp-vim/pull/14).

This is what you get: http://bl.ocks.org/anonymous/raw/9442865

cpp-vim adds support for other C++11 stuff too.

Comment: Works great, they use the `syn region` syntax highlighting command to recognize raw string literals - such that also multi-line raw string literals are highlighted corrected. Directly cloning the git repository into a [pathogen](https://github.com/tpope/vim-pathogen) bundle directory works, too.

Answer (score 7):

Add this

```
syntax match cString 'R"\([^(]*\)(\_.*)\1"'
```

to your custom C++ syntax file (normally `~/.vim/syntax/cpp.vim` ; create this file if you don't have one).

Comment: for sure, it's minimal addition just to support c++11, it's used to add stuff to the official built in vim syntax files.

Comment: sometimes, for any obscure reason, things don't get added to the official vim files...

Comment: @maxschlepzig I have somewhat fixed multiline strings (added `\_.*`) but it's really not that robust and will not match wchar_t strings, unicode strings, ... cpp-vim has much better support for c++11 features, use it.

Answer (score 0):

A tiny tweak on the above syntax rule:

```
syntax match cString 'R"\([^(]*\)(\_.\{-})\1"'
```

The original attempts to greedily select the longest match; so if you have multiple raw strings in a file (using the same open/close pattern) is would break.
This one is non-greedy, and should match correctly.
Thank you so much for the original though, it was a huge help to me!