# How can I change the match pattern of a default syntax group?

Tags: vim

I would like to change the syntax rules for C++ raw strings so that raw strings highlight as if they were not strings, but keep string highlighting the same in all other cases. This is the inverse of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22674375/how-to-exclude-c-raw-string-literals-from-syntax-highlighting-in-vim) question (I like the behavior of 7.4). Knowledge of C++ is not necessary for this question. I am on a shared machine and cannot directly edit the default syntax files.

`syntax list cCppString` lists

```
cCppString     xxx start=/\(L\|u\|u8\|U\|R\|LR\|u8R\|uR\|UR\)\="/ skip=/\\\\\|\\"\|\\$/ end=/$/ end=/"/  excludenl contains=cSpecial,cFormat,@Spell
                   links to cString
```

and `syntax list cString` shows something similar. The offending patterns are `R\|LR\|u8R\|uR\|UR`

In the default syntax file `vim80/syntax/c.vim` I see the following lines

```
syn region>...cString>>.......start=+\(L\|u\|u8\|U\|R\|LR\|u8R\|uR\|UR\)\="+ skip=+\\\\\|\\"+ end=+"+ contains=cSpecial,cFormat,@Spell extend
syn region >..cCppString>.....start=+\(L\|u\|u8\|U\|R\|LR\|u8R\|uR\|UR\)\="+ skip=+\\\\\|\\"\|\\$+ excludenl end=+"+ end='$' contains=cSpecial,cFormat,@Spell
```

I need to remove these patterns but keep everything else intact. I've tried redefining them in `.vim/after/syntax/c.vim` with things like

```
syn region>...cString>>.......start=+\(L\|u\|u8\|U\)\="+ skip=+\\\\\|\\"+ end=+"+ contains=cSpecial,cFormat,@Spell extend
```

but this concatenates instead of overwriting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to override the syntax, then start by clearing the previous rules, then add yours.

```
syn clear cString cCppString
syn region cString
  \ start=+\(L\|u\|u8\|U\)\="+
  \ skip=+\\\\\|\\"+
  \ end=+"+
  \ contains=cSpecial,cFormat,@Spell
  \ extend
syn region cCppString
  \ start=+\(L\|u\|u8\|U\)\="+
  \ skip=+\\\\\|\\"\|\\$+
  \ excludenl
  \ end=+"+
  \ end='$'
  \ contains=cSpecial,cFormat,@Spell
```

Also note that the correct location for the file to override these is `~/.vim/after/syntax/c.vim`, since Vim wants to source a file named `syntax/c.vim` and directory `~/.vim/after` is included by default late in `'runtimepath'`.